# unable to get kwargs from get_queryset of ListView

Tags: django, listview, django-queryset

I want to get pk, or id of each post in 'views.py' so that I can use it for filtering and getting extra data in 'get_context_data'(Eventually, I want to check access of currently logged in user to each post). When website runs, it shows error message "KeyError at /post".

What could be a problem in this?

I was trying to apply example in django's official website(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).
I couldn't see a significant difference between this example and mine.

## views.py

```
class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Post.objects.filter(pk=self.post)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(PostList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['post_info'] = self.post
         context['check_access'] = Access.objects.filter(sender
         return context
```

## post/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('<int:pk>', PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
]
```

I expected to see pk or id of each post but it shows below instead:

```
self.post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
args    
()
kwargs  
{}
self    
<post.views.PostList object at 0x107ab0ba8>
```

Comment: Well your `url` does not contain a `pk`. Can you share your `urlpatterns`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just added urls.py! (updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the URL is missing the primary key. You have to include it, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
]
```

Then you can query this with:

```
localhost:8000/post/123
```

with `123` the primary key for which you want to retrieve data.

This however does *not* look like a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). A `ListView` should be used when you render a *list* of objects. This looks more like a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

The nice thing about a `DetailView` is that it even automatically filters on primary key and slug. It will automatically raise a 404 response if no such object exists.

So you likely want to use:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'post/post_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['check_access'] = Access.objects.filter(...)
         return context
```

The [**`context_object_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name) specifies the name of the template variable for that object.

Comment: My PostDetailView works using 'DetailView'. I wanted to get pk of each object in views.py. However, I can't find a way to pk from 'self'. So I looked up in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/ for an example. However, it was an example of getting user information from self.kwargs, not the pk information of post itself. Are there any ways to get pk of each post in views.py for ListView?

Comment: @user3422616: but the URL needs to pass the primary key. A server is stateless. So it means it evidently can not remember the "previous pk". You thus use the URL (or another mechanism) to retrieve the pk, like changing the URL such that it contains a pk. A `ListView` however, usually does *not* have a `pk`), since it lists items. Sometimes it contains the `pk` of a "parent" class, and then it is again in the URL.

Comment: You can however when you iterate over the queryset, retrieve it with `{% for object in object_list %} {{ object.pk }} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Yes. Using object_list works fine. I just wanted to find a way to get data of each post in views.py instead of using template tag. hm... but thanks! :)

Comment: @user3422616: you can also iterate over the objects in your view, like in the `get_context_data`, you can `for obj in context['object_list']: print(obj.pk)` (of course you can do more sensical things than just printing the `pk`).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have your URL pattern as follows,

```
path('posts/<status>/', PostsListView.as_view()),
```

The kwargs can be accessible from the self if you are using class based views

```
status=self.kwargs.get('status',None)
if status: queryset=queryset.filter(status=status)
```

Since the kwargs argument is not directly accessible in the get_queryset(self) function